# 1931 home repairs. Radiator connections need redoing

Tags: plumbing, heating

Radiator valves cracked and was corroded/welded on.   Removed all the corroded parts and got replacements but accidentally cut the steam in line at a diagonal,  one side is untouched but the other is cut down maybe a centimeter into the threads.  Still 3/4 inch of threads left   Clean cut  am I safe to use the pipe or do I have to go in through the ceiling underneath and replace the whole pipe?

Comment: Try it and see.

Comment: Pictures would help.